# How to access Runnable during Thread creation inside ThreadFactory?

Tags: java, threadpool

I have a `ThreadPoolExecutor` I've created with a custom `ThreadFactory`. When I call the `execute()` method passing my `Runnable`, a new `Thread` is created using my custom `ThreadFactory`. The problem is I can't find a way to access information inside the `Runnable`.

For example, I have a class `Job` that implements `Runnable`. Inside `Job`, I have a property `A` that I would like to access in the `newThread()` method of my custom `ThreadFactory`. The problem is that I can't cast the `Runnable` passed as parameter to `Job` since it's not a `Job` instance, it is an instance of the `ThreadPoolExecutor.Worker` class, and this class is `private`.

Comment: You will never be able to do this, since the thread pool does not use one thread for every runnable you submit, that's why it's a thread pool, it reuses threads for your runnables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are either misusing or misunderstanding what thread pool does. The process of creating threads and submitting/running tasks is completely decoupled. Thread pool decides when create a new thread and it might not be related to any new task submitted at all.

And finally remember that one thread is most likely reused across several `Runnable`s.

Comment: Oh you're right! And now I remember why I used ThreadPool for this, it was just a hack...